# React API call - text with HTML insert doesn't work as code

Tags: html, reactjs, escaping

I make an API call for an element in React using following code:

```
 <div>{props.text}</div>
```

After receiving the response, it is displayed in a block. What I want to achieve is to insert new line(s) with HTML. I tried using \n, br / and such but it simply displays the text and is not interpreted as code.
Is there any possibility to escape that?
Thanks!

Comment: do you mean: you're making an API call that provides a `text` and you want your text not to be displayed as a block, but into lines  ?

Comment: yes it returns a text string - I would like to inject HTML into this text so that it is interpreted as such, not as plain text as it is now. I would like to split this text into separate lines by using br tag or something similar

Answer (score 0):

You can apply some javascript logic for this  :

**Example** for splitting a text into separate lines,  in each line 8 words   :

```js
const str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos nobis iure eveniet consequuntur porro, earum culpa amet nesciunt totam, corrupti hic? Iure, animi, ratione '


const str1 = str.split(' ')
const upstr =  str1.slice(0,8).join(' ') + '\n' + str1.slice(8,16).join(' ') + '\n' + str1.slice(16,24).join(' ') + '\n' 
console.log(upstr)
```

if you have  a big text you  can use a `for loop`